# How to hide tooltip of hidden chart -- Kendo Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am hiding the chart using [hidden] property on click of series Item. But tooltip is visible until user removes the cursor from the clicked area.

Is there any way I can hide the tooltip too.

stackblitz reproducing the issue:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-czxxqb?file=app/app.component.ts

---

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <div [hidden]="hidechart">
        <kendo-chart
            [categoryAxis]="{ categories: categories }"            
            (seriesClick)="onSeriesClick($event)"
            (seriesHover)="onSeriesHover($event)">
            <kendo-chart-title text="Gross domestic product growth /GDP annual %/"></kendo-chart-title>
            <kendo-chart-legend position="bottom" orientation="horizontal"></kendo-chart-legend>
            <kendo-chart-tooltip format="{0}%"></kendo-chart-tooltip>
            <kendo-chart-series>
                <kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let item of series"
                    type="line" style="smooth" [data]="item.data" [name]="item.name">
                </kendo-chart-series-item>
            </kendo-chart-series>
        </kendo-chart>
        </div>
        <event-log title="Event log" [events]="events"></event-log>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public events: string[] = [];
    public hidechart: boolean = false;
    public series: any[] = [{
            name: 'India',
            data: [3.907, 7.943, 7.848, 9.284, 9.263, 9.801, 3.890, 8.238, 9.552, 6.855]
        }, {
            name: 'Russian Federation',
            data: [4.743, 7.295, 7.175, 6.376, 8.153, 8.535, 5.247, -7.832, 4.3, 4.3]
        }, {
            name: 'Germany',
            data: [0.010, -0.375, 1.161, 0.684, 3.7, 3.269, 1.083, -5.127, 3.690, 2.995]
        }, {
            name: 'World',
            data: [1.988, 2.733, 3.994, 3.464, 4.001, 3.939, 1.333, -2.245, 4.339, 2.727]
        }];

    public categories: number[] = [2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011];

    public onRender(): void {
        this.log('render');
    }

  

    public onSeriesClick(e): void {
        this.log('seriesClick', e);
        this.hidechart = true;
    }

    public onSeriesHover(e): void {
        this.log('seriesHover', e);
    }

    private log(event: string, arg: any = null): void {
        this.events.push(`${event}`);
        console.log(arg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get a reference to the chart

```
@ViewChild(ChartComponent, { static: true })
public chart: ChartComponent;
```

Then, before hiding the chart, call `this.chart.tooltipInstance.hide();`

```
public onSeriesClick(e): void {
    this.chart.tooltipInstance.hide();
    this.hidechart = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Solution Mike. Its works. One observation when unhiding the div the particular series item which was clicked if  hovered does not show the tooltip if hovered. Although hovering on others series works